# Console Application - Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, iis-7, console-application

I have a console application and I am trying to run .exe file on server. But I am getting the below error.

> Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application

I have developed the console application in 3.5 framework and the server have 4.0 framework.

Shall I develop the application in 2.0 or 3.0 framework?

Comment: I once had this happen and it was because the computer attempting to run the application had `.NET 4 Client Profile` instead of the full installation. Try installing the full .NET Framework.

Comment: What OS is the server running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4.0 Framework does not include 2.0-3.5.

You need either install version 3.5 on the server OR add entry in the config of your application to allow it to run under 4.0.

```
<supportedRuntime>V4.0</supportedRuntime>
```

Check [When executing an application on .net 4.0, complied under .net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921976/when-executing-an-application-on-net-4-0-complied-under-net-2-0) and [app.config <supportedRuntime>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961600/app-config-supportedruntime) for details.

Comment: Yes I got the solution,
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup> Thank you very munch

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the **Target Framework** for the application. It's on the Project properties.

Comment: Thank you for you replay, But I dot have VS-2010 installed on my pc. I try with VS 2008 but not found the 4.0 framework. How to change the target framework for the console application with VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create .Net 4.0 Application with Visual Studio 2008, If you have 2010 VS IDE, you can create .Net 3.5 Application.

[image]

You can go ahead with VS 2010 with .Net 3.5 applciation